# How to write an exception catching code works in Python2.4 to Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there anyway to write an exception catch code that's compatible from python 2.4 to python 3?

Like this code:

```
# only works in python 2.4 to 2.7
try:
    pass
except Exception,e:
   print(e)

# only works in python 2.6 to 3.3
try:
    pass
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Comment: A lot of projects maintain their code for python 2, and use [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) to automatically convert it to python 3 as necessary.  That is usually easier than trying to write code that is compatible with both (this probably won't be the most difficult issue you come across).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Trying to write code that works in both Python 2 and Python 3 is ultimately rather futile, because of the sheer number of differences between them. Indeed, a lot of projects are now maintained in separate Python 2 and Python 3 versions as a result.

That said, if you're hell-bent on doing this in a super-portable way...

```
import sys
try:
    ...
except Exception:
    t, e = sys.exc_info()[:2]
    print(e)
```

Comment: Thank you nneonneo for your answer, and thank you @gnibbler for your tip :-)

Comment: @gnibbler: I believe it is..."The information returned is specific both to the current thread and to the current stack frame."

Comment: If you're using [Logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) classes (and really, you should be), you don't even need to ``import sys`` and use inscrutable code to print your exceptions - you can just call ``Logger.exception("message")`` or the class method ``logging.exception("message")`` and the exception message and/or stack trace will be included in the logger output.